# How to Prevent Login Challenge Using [Authorize] WebAPI Core?

Tags: angular, authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

My api needs to be called by authenticated and unauthenticated users from an Angular application. Apparently adding the [Authorize] attribute automatically sends a 401 status code back with the following headers and forces a challenge:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="bla.bla.bla"
```

I don't want users that don't have a way to authenticate to see the challenge as they open the page, but I do want users that are in the domain to be automatically authenticated. So I thought I could create a method to "check" if that user is authenticated or not, and if he/she is I would then get the users information, otherwise, just display a login button (that would then call the GetUser method):

```
[HttpGet("Check")]
public IActionResult Check()
{
     return Ok(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
}
```

The idea was that if that returned true, I could just call the GetUser() method, which has the [Authorize] attribute. The problem is, if I don't have the [Authorize] attribute for the Check method, it always returns false, if I add [Authorize] it works fine, but it challenges users that are not already authenticated.

Here's the GetUser method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult GetUser()
{
    try
    {
                if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    var user = userService.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
                    return Ok(user);
                } else
                {
                    return Unauthorized();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Error getting user!");
            }
        }
```

Basically what I want is the Check method to not force a challenge. I just want to know if the user is authenticated or not. I looked up ways to remove the WWW-Authenticate header, but couldn't get it to work.

Angular call:

```
    getUser(): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get<User>(environment.apiUrl + '/Users', { withCredentials: true });
  }

  check(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.get<boolean>(environment.apiUrl + '/Users/Check', { withCredentials: true });
  }
}
```

Any suggestions, better ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Use `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute?

Comment: Adding AllowAnnonymous or having just AllowAnnonymous didn't make a difference, it behaved like there were no attributes at all. It still returns false even though user is authenticated.

Comment: Of course, you do realize that WebAPI is stateless right? You will need to pass in a token or w/e mechicaism you are using to web api for every `request`

Comment: Yes, and it is stateless this way. All I want is the Check method to accept the token and return if it's valid or not, without forcing a challenge. Maybe this is something I could do client side?

Comment: I think what happens is, without the authorize attribute, the call does not return Authentication header in the preflight, that way not authentication information is sent from the client

Comment: In companies where you use integrated security, you need to configure your browser (manually or with gpo)... They need to use: integrated security in order to use challenge/response from ntlm